# Can I use shared hosting for dynamic website?

Tags: shared-hosting

Can anyone help me

We'd like to create our startup MVP dynamic website with transaction, scheduling(calendar) and matching system using Python(django) and mongodb, can we use a shared hosting for that? (if yes, can you  guys recommend?) reason is that no one in our team knows linux yet if we use vps.

beginner here and we don't have tech lead yet in our team  we're trying to do it on our own (funding reasons).

We believe in our idea but we're short in resources. I hope you guys can help us. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi yka, your question doesn't seem to be about a specific programming problem, which makes it off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @LarsKristensen can you suggest where I could seek help for this kind of matter? any other community that would be able to help me? It will be a great help, Thank you.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you are asking about, so it is dificult to suggest anything. What have you tried so far (apart from asking here)?

Comment: Yes, you can use shared hosting which, in my book at least, means that your app will run on a compute resources shared with other apps. Generally this will be cheaper but also have lower performance and more easily be affected by the "noisy neighbour" problem. When you use shared hosting (or any PaaS for hosting) you will have to also use a PaaS solution for your MongoDB (or a VM but that's not shared hosting). Doing an internet search for "Django shared hosting" should provide you with options.

Comment: @yka Yes you can use shared hosting but make sure it supports python/django applications. I would suggest check NameCheap servers. Also I would recommend using  https://www.pythonanywhere.com/ , its pretty straight forward and you will have no issue deploying your django website on it.

Comment: Hi @Zayn, thank you so much! with the mentioned providers, is it easy to transfer to dedicated hosting if in the future we plan to?

Comment: @yka Yes it wouldn't be a problem. You will have to change your DNS servers for that if you plan to move to different hosting.

Comment: cool! thank you so much! @Zayn